# vim - move cursor after inserted text

Tags: vim

Is there way how to move cursor after inserted (by pasting) multiline text?
When doing inline insertion (paste), `p` and `P` works just fine. But if I paste multiline text, my cursor regardless of `p` or `P` moves to the top of new text.

How can leave my cursor after the new text after `p` or `P`?

Comment: "insert" in your question means "paste" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using mark is one way. but for `p or P`, if you want to leave your cursor after the newly pasted text, there is build-in `gp`

`:h gp`  for detail

```
["x]gp          Just like "p", but leave the cursor just after the new
            text.  {not in Vi}


["x]gP          Just like "P", but leave the cursor just after the new
            text.  {not in Vi}
```

Comment: Good call.  This is the better answer for the OP's question.  I will leave mine as it can be used for more than just `p` and `P`.

Comment: usually the cursor position is not so critical for daily text editing, (except for macro recording). but it is very important trick to play vimgolf! :)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `]` mark to move to the end of the pasted text.  This excerpt is taken from `:help ']`:

```
After executing an operator the Cursor is put at the beginning of the text
that was operated upon.  After a put command ("p" or "P") the cursor is
sometimes placed at the first inserted line and sometimes on the last inserted
character.  The four commands above put the cursor at either end.  Example:
After yanking 10 lines you want to go to the last one of them: "10Y']".  After
inserting several lines with the "p" command you want to jump to the lowest
inserted line: "p']".  This also works for text that has been inserted.
```